# Optimization stops prematurely (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying my best to work it out with fmincon in MATLAB. When I call the function, I get one of the two following errors:

Number of function evaluation exceeded, or

Number of iteration exceeded.

And when I look at the solution so far, it is way off the one intended (I know so because I created a minimum vector).

Now even if I increase any of the tolerance constraint or max number of iterations, I still get the same problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the dimension? did you try starting around the known solution? are you providing the gradient and hessian?

Comment: No, I'm providing the equality matrix and vector: Aeq and beq. I'm now only considering the problem of L1 minimization with only equality constraints, but still the simulation is taking so much time and giving wrong results (no where near), or the solver is producing a memory error. I mean, how could the JPEG compress an image in 1ms with this memory/time overhead?

Answer (score 1):

First, if your problem can actually be cast as linear or quadratic programming, do that first.

Otherwise, have you tried seeding it with different starting values `x0`? If it's starting in a bad place, it may be much harder to get to the optimum.

If it's possible for you to provide the gradient of the function, that can help the optimizer tremendously (though obviously only if you can find it some way other than numerical differentiation). Similarly, if you can provide the (full or sparse) Hessian relatively cheaply, you're golden.

You can also try [using a different algorithm in the solver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brhkghv-18.html#bsbqd7i).

Basically, `fmincon` by default has almost no info about the function it's trying to optimize, and providing more can be extremely helpful. If you can tell us more about the objective function, we might be able to give more tips.

Comment: You said everything I was going to say, but better. +1 and bravo.

Comment: @Dougal

"""First, if your problem can actually be cast as linear or quadratic programming, do that first"""


Already done so

I'm starting with all zero vectors, hmm, I'll try doing that.

It's the L1 norm, I don't know if it is differentiable.

So, the objective function is actually of column vector of pixels. So what I am trying to do is apply this function to the entire columns of an image. It's something related to atomic decompostion.

Comment: @ToniAz I don't really understand what you mean. If it's a linear or quadratic programming problem, you shouldn't be using `fmincon', but instead `linprog` or `quadprog`. Also, if your objective function is really the L1 norm, you can do that in closed form: the minimum of `||x - q||_1` is just `q`.... But the L1 norm is differentiable (except at 0); the partial w.r.t. a component is just the derivative of the absolute value of that component, i.e. its sign times the interior derivative: for the straight-up L1 norm, that's just 1 or -1. So `grad_x( || x ||_1 )` is just `sign(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The L1 norm is not differentiable. That can make it difficult for the algorithm to converge to a point where one of the residuals is zero. I suspect this is why number of iterations limits are exceeded. If your original problem is

```
 min norm(residual(x),1)

 s.t. Aeq*x=beq
```

you can reformulate the problem differentiably, as follows

```
 min sum(b)

 s.t.  -b(i)<=residual(x,i)<=b(i)

        Aeq*x=beq
```

where residual(x,i) is the i-th residual, x is the original vector of unknowns, and b is a further unknown vector of bounds that you add to the problem.